# Creating and reusing custom elements with jQuery vs Polymer vs Dust.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer, dust.js

I've written some widgets to use in my web app, and I'd like to be able to plug these widgets in throughout the app without pasting big chunks of widget code. So far I've been writing custom HTML tags and using jQuery selectors and CSS to populate and style my tags. The end result allows me to write `<myTag></myTag>` anywhere on a page, and have my custom widget appear.

Recently, I've learned about Dust JS and Google's Polymer Project. My understanding is that Dust would allow me to write a template and "swap out" parts of the template with my content, while Polymer would allow me to create custom HTML tags as I've been trying to do and place them wherever I'd like.

Would it benefit me to use Dust or Polymer? What is the difference between those two options and simply using jQuery to select my tags and plug in my widget/styles? Obviously these are three drastically different libraries/frameworks, but it seems to me that there is some overlap when it comes to my use case. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Edit: Say I have a plain old HTML page. The question I'm getting at is what would prevent me from using `{myCustomWidget}` in Dust to "plug in" my widget throughout the app, other than the fact that this may not be standard usage? Similarly, why would I use Polymer to create "shortcuts" for my widgets over using a jQuery selector?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a ton about Dust, but I've made fairly heavy use of both jQuery and Polymer. Someone with more Dust experience should totally weigh in. It looks like one of the main advantages of Dust is that it's designed for efficient server-side rendering. It's also format agnostic whereas jQuery and Polymer are both specialized for HTML.

Polymer is designed for the use case of creating encapsulated widgets that can be easily reused. It's got a few advantages over rolling your own system with jQuery:

- A Polymer element can be imported with one line, and the import will pull in its html, js, and css, and it will register the element within the page.
- Polymer has support for data binding, meaning that you typically don't have to write code to ensure that the widget is updated after some data changes. When the data changes, all of the widgets that are interacting with that respond immediately and automatically.
- Polymer interops really well with jQuery, so if you've got a site that's doing a lot of jQuery style interaction today you can gradually introduce Polymer elements and they'll play well with the rest of your page. e.g.

  - `$('<my-slider>').appendTo('body') // append the slider widget to the page`
  - `$('my-slider').attr('value') // get the current value of the slider`
  - `$('my-slider').attr('value', 100) // set the value of all sliders`
  - etc
- The styling of a polymer element is encapsulated, meaning that a widget will not mess up the rest of the page with its CSS, and the enclosing page won't mess up the styling of the widget (though the enclosing page can style the widget it has to be fairly intentional, just setting something like `* { padding: 5px; }` won't throw everything off).

There's great docs at http://www.polymer-project.org/ (and after getting started, I strongly recommend the API docs, they're quite complete and informative: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html )

Comment: After using Dust JS on another project for some time, and learning that it serves a different purpose than what I had thought, I realized that jQuery vs Polymer was a more appropriate comparison and your answer helped me learn more about Polymer and how it would be different from rolling my own custom tags.

Answer (score 3):

I've not used Polymer before but I've used Dust and jQuery extensively.

Dust is simply a template library, just like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/),[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and the myriad of other template libraries out there. It's written in javascript and can be used with NodeJS or can easily run in the browser if you're building client side applications.

Both Dust and jQuery can be used together. Dust would render your HTML templates and as always, jQuery would be used to manipulate them and do whatever else you normally do with jQuery such as listen to events and handle them accordingly.

It's important to note that the two aren't alternatives but rather they work together. Dust cannot do the things that jQuery does and is not meant to. Dust works very well when you have large templates that require partials and blocks.

Comment: I guess I understand how Dust is _meant_ to be used, but what is to stop someone from using `{myWidget}` as a custom widget and sprinkling it throughout the web app? Say I have a plain old HTML page and I'd like to include my widget in three different places. Are there any advantages to using jQuery instead of Dust to "plug in" my widget, other than the fact doing so in this way may not be standard usage for Dust?

Comment: If it's a widget with lots of javascript stuff going on then I'd do it all in jQuery. If you just want to include a HTML widget in multiple pages then I'd do it in Dust and include it as a partial wherever you want to use it.

Comment: But is there a reason why? I'm trying to make an educated decision based on why one option is better than the rest while also learning the proper usage for each of these libraries/frameworks

Comment: If you're doing DOM manipulation, calculations, responding to events etc. then Dust simply cannot do it. It's only supposed to render templates. jQuery on the other hand can do all of that. It depends purely on what your widget is going to do. Is it just HTML or is it HTML with event handling? I usually reserve using Dust for rendering decent amounts of HTML and when I have a need of Dust's partials and blocks (each of which jQuery doesn't have). If I don't need complex template rendering, I just use jQuery to render the HTML and then handle any events arising from that HTML.

Comment: @Simon I am begginer to dust. So, I have a question about it. Can you please take a look at it on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347515/evaluate-dustjs-variables-from-jquery

Answer (score 1):

At its core, Polymer is a platform of polyfills for the current implementation of the WC3 web component recommendation as well as some aspects of ECMA 6 such as Object.observe() and WeakMap. Included in the Platform are the libraries NodeBind and TemplateBinding which enable observable (two-way) custom element data-binding.

Dustjs is an asynchronous logic-less templating engine for client-side and server-side(Nodejs)
rendering. There is no native concept of an observable in Dustjs(as is the case for most template engines), meaning two-way data-binding is outside the scope of the project. However, the PayPal roadmap for Dustjs indicates two-way data-binding may receive official support by the end of 2014.

That being said, NodeBind and observe-js are separate repos not necessarily tied to the Polymer custom element implementation, meaning you can use them in your own projects--which is exactly what I did.

My biggest criticism of client-side rendering frameworks like Polymer (and in some respects, angularjs), is that they are not SEO compatible. So I actually combined NodeBind with Dustjs to make my own two-way data-bound custom element implementation derived from the Polymer platform. The idea is that Dustjs renders the template server-side(or even client-side, if SPA) and then upon rendering, you bind the Dust context to an observable and then parse the template fragment for attributes and keys, binding them to a path observer which maps to the observable. So, the bulk of the task is to write your own parser. The good news is that you can use the Dust parser to help your code. The bad news is that if you want to support arbitrary depths, it is far from a simple task(involves quite a bit of recursion). The other non-trivial task is to support path observer rebinding in the event of model list additions and subtractions.

A final note: Dustjs inheritance offers a superior way to reference your custom elements without relying on HTML Imports and ajax like Polymer.

You can do something like this:

```
{>my-element}
```

simply as a partial. And in my-element.html

```
<my-element>
<ui-template id="my-element-frag">...</ui-template>
</my-element>
```

this does require a second-step in your build process(grunt or gulp) that requires you to not only compile the external files but to parse your external files for your "template tags" and compile those as separate templates, which can then be referenced by, say, the id attribute(as the template name).