# Evaluate DustJS variables from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dust.js

I want to append some HTML containing DustJS variables using jQuery. Here is what I am trying to do in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $("tr").click(function(){
        $(this).after('<tr class="row-details">\
                          <td></td>\
                          <td colspan="4">\
                            <table class="sortable draggable">\
                              <thead>\
                                  <tr>\
                                      <th class="col-itemName">Item Name</th>\
                                      <th class="col-quantity">Quantity</th>\
                                      <th class="col-rate">Rate</th>\
                                      <th class="col-amount">Amount</th>\
                                  </tr>\
                              </thead>\
                              <tbody>\
                                  {#items}\
                                    <tr>\
                                      <td>{.item.itemName}</td>\
                                      <td>{.quantity}</td>\
                                      <td>{.rate}</td>\
                                      <td>{@math key="{.quantity}" method="multiply" operand="{.rate}"/}</td>\
                                    </tr>\
                                  {/items}\
                              </tbody>\
                            </table>\
                          </td>\
                        </tr>');
    });
  });
```

Here is my output:

[image]

How do I evaluate those variables???

Comment: @Gothdo I can't understand anything on that page. What are you trying to explain?

Comment: You're just adding HTML with jQuery. There's nothing in your code which indicates you're using Dust. How is jQuery supposed to know what to do with the Dust parameters? Before you try to render the HTML in the DOM, you need to pass the HTML string to `dust.render` in order to have the variables print.

Comment: @Simon can you please give me an example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    $("tr").click(function () {
        var self = this,
            templateData = {}; // some set of data you want to render in the template

        dust.render(templateString, templateData, function (err, out) {
                if (err && typeof console !== 'undefined' && console.error) {
                    console.error(err);
                }

                $(self).after(out);
        });
    });

    var templateString = '<tr class="row-details">\
                          <td></td>\
                          <td colspan="4">\
                            <table class="sortable draggable">\
                              <thead>\
                                  <tr>\
                                      <th class="col-itemName">Item Name</th>\
                                      <th class="col-quantity">Quantity</th>\
                                      <th class="col-rate">Rate</th>\
                                      <th class="col-amount">Amount</th>\
                                  </tr>\
                              </thead>\
                              <tbody>\
                                  {#items}\
                                    <tr>\
                                      <td>{.item.itemName}</td>\
                                      <td>{.quantity}</td>\
                                      <td>{.rate}</td>\
                                      <td>{@math key="{.quantity}" method="multiply" operand="{.rate}"/}</td>\
                                    </tr>\
                                  {/items}\
                              </tbody>\
                            </table>\
                          </td>\
                        </tr>';
});
```

Comment: Here you define the templateData on the fly, but I have data coming from database in the .dust page. So, the element which was clicked will be the current context for those dust variables. Then how can I get the data. Or do I have to have an ajax call here? If so, then how can I get the Id of the currently selected tr?

Comment: Ok, I got that. But now coming to your code: I get an error saying that dust is not defined. So, how can I define dust in jQuery??

Comment: You need to include the Dust script in your page, just like you've included jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After including Dust, I got another error: Template not found. I solved it by using `dust.renderSource` instead of `dust.render`